# Refactoring a method to find the max of any number of arguments RUBY

Tags: ruby, methods

The original task was to **Define a method named max that takes two numbers as arguments and returns the largest of them.** Now I need to **Refactor the max method to find the max of any number of arguments**. I'm stumped

Here is my code for the first task which returns the largest number:

```
 def max(num1, num2)
  num1 = 2
  num2 = 3
  if num1 < num2
    return num2
  end
end
```

Comment: @sawa the question is right before the code in bold... along with the original  task.

Comment: Your method does not work as expected: it returns `3` regardless of the given arguments. You should fix it before attempting to refactor it.

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck here?

Comment: obviously the task is the question here. i'm not here to argue, just to get help with the task that i provided. i already got that help from multiple others. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not allowed to use `Array#max`, you can do the following:

```
def maxx *args
  args.reduce { |memo, obj|
    obj > memo ? obj : memo
  }
end

p maxx 2,3,9,5,4,3,10,8
#=> 10
```

#### Explanation

Here's a slightly more verbose, un-refactored version which may be easier to read. `*args` catches all your arguments into an array `args`. In the example `args = [2, 3, 9, 5, 4, 3, 10, 8]`.

```
def maxx(*args)
  args.reduce {|memo, obj|
    if obj > memo
      memo = obj
    else
      memo = memo
    end
  }
end

p maxx(2,3,9,5,4,3,10,8)
#=> 10
```

`reduce` goes through each element `obj` from your `args` array storing it as the new `memo` only if `obj` is bigger than the current `memo`. By default `memo` starts with `args[0]`, `2` in this case. And `obj` starts with `args[1]`, namely `3`.

**Step one:**

- `memo` is `2`; obj is 3;
- new `memo` is `3` because 3 > 2

**Step two:**

- `memo` is `3`; `obj` is `9`;
- new `memo` is `9` because 9 > 3

**Step three:**

- `memo` is `9`; `obj` is `5`;
- new `memo` is `9` because 9 > 5

**Step four:**

- `memo` is `9`; `obj` is `4`;
- new `memo` is `9` because 9 > 4

.
.
.

**Step seven:**

- `memo` is `10`; `obj` is 8;
- new `memo` is `10` because 10 > 8

The final new `memo` is what's returned by `reduce`, which is of course the maximum `10`. For more information on [`Array#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). In the refactored original answer I've used a [`ternary operator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if) which is basically a short way of writing a simple [`if-expression`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression).

Comment: this works, however I do not understand it. if you could give me the steps with explanation, that would be awesome. Thanks for the help @sagarpandya82

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. i'm new to ruby so this really helped me out. i appreciate the help. @sagarpandya82

Answer (score 1):

Please check this :

Method definition:

```
def find_max *input
 return input.max
end
```

Method invocation and get max of provided input numbers:

```
puts find_max(1,4,2,3)
puts find_max(8,5,9,2,0,14,1)
```

Comment: `find_max (1,4,2,3)` – that kind of whitespace usage results in a syntax error.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for pointing out that !!! Spaces came up when i added code here, I think its obvious for a ruby developer to understand there are no spaces. Removing those.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are not allowed to use Array#max and we need to check from only two number. I would preferably use this,

```
def max (a,b)
  a>b ? a : b
end
```

if we can use Array#max, and any number of arguments,

```
array = [a, b, c, ...]
def max(array)
  array.max
end
```

Comment: It doesn't specify that I cant use Array#max. Also it's to find the maximum for any number of arguments not just 2.